# Unable to pass Null Value in Date

Tags: java

I need to compare two value (date) from query .

```
String myFormatString = "yyyyMMdd";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString);
```

(query)

```
Date date1 = df.parse(rs.getString(8));
Date date2= df.parse(rs.getString(9));
```

Actually i can get the value (date) i want from query and can pass into 
date1 and date2 . But when i got null value from database for date2 ,
i got 'NullPointerException' error. I need to compare date 1 and date 2 then 
will set the larger date to report. Any idea?

---

Dear All, Thanks for your advices. It is really helpful to me. Finally i found the way to solve .

```
try {
        Date date1 = df.parse(rs.getString(8));
        Date date2 = df.parse(rs.getString(9));
        if(date1.compareTo(date2) > 0)
         { Date = rs.getString(8);
         }
         else if(date1.compareTo(date2) < 0)
         {
          Date = rs.getString(9);
          }
             else
            {
         Date = rs.getString(8);
            }


        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        Date=rs.getString(8);
       }
```

Comment: Shouldn't be your date format like this `yyyy-MM-dd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date object don't accept null constructor. You may need to create temporary variables first and make sure they are not null. If one of those are null, may be you can say otherone is larger (if that is what you are expecting & your business logic is?).

```
Date date1 = null; 
if((rs.getString(8)!=null) && (!"".equals(rs.getString(8))))
{    
 date1 = df.parse(rs.getString(8)); 
}  

Date date2 = null; 
if((rs.getString(9)!=null) && (!"".equals(rs.getString(9))))
{    
 date2 = df.parse(rs.getString(9)); 
}
```

Then do date comparison between date1 & date2.

Comment: hi thanks for your help. when i compare , it also get that NullPointerException Error.  if(date1.compareTo(date2) > 0)         System.out.println("Second Date is initialized before First Date");
       else if(date1.compareTo(date2) < 0)
       System.out.println("Second Date is initialized after First Date");
       else
       System.out.println("First Date and Second Date are equal"); how shall i do??

Comment: I edited my code now. Try that, ! symbol should be inside, because of that it seems if blocks are not getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

Before parse you check whether date string is null or not,

```
Date date1 = null;
Date date2 = null;
if((rs.getString(8)!=null) && !(rs.getString(8).equals(""))){
    date1 = df.parse(rs.getString(8));
}

if((rs.getString(9)!=null) && !(rs.getString(9).equals(""))){
    date2 = df.parse(rs.getString(9));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is such that there are cases when the database would return `null` for `date2`, then it would be a good idea to use exception handling:

```
try {
    Date date1 = df.parse(rs.getString(8));
    Date date2 = df.parse(rs.getString(9));
    ...
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    // Do something/nothing if date2 is null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put null value for Date object. If you passing null value for date, then you can't compare the Date. In this case you need to handle the Exception.

```
    Date yourReportDate = new Date();

    try {
        Date date1 = df.parse(rs.getString(8);
        Date date2 = df.parse(rs.getString(9);

        if(date1.getTime()>date2.getTime())
        {
            yourReportDate.setTime(date1.getTime());
        }else
        {
            yourReportDate.setTime(date2.getTime());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```